# How can time crystals be useful in qRAM design?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-computer, time-crystals

A time crystal is a phase of a matter which is ordered in time, similar to classical crystals which are ordered spatially. In other words, the structure of a time crystal is ever-changing but with some period. In fact, time crystals are quantum systems whose ground states are characterized by periodic motion (so-called *non-equilibrium matter*), e.g. periodically changing spins in a chain of ions. See more for example [here](https://futurism.com/quantum-breakthrough-physicists-have-once-more-created-time-crystals) and on [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_crystal).

Time crystals were proposed in 2012 by Frank Wilczek as a theoretical concept, however, later their existence was proved (see e.g. references on Wiki page). In July 2021, Google claimed that its team prepared the time crystal on Sycamore processor, see the paper [Observation of Time-Crystalline Eigenstate Order on a Quantum Processor](https://arxiv.org/abs/2107.13571).

In many articles on time crystals, I see a statement that time crystals can help to design quantum memories (qRAM) and on this forum e.g. [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/319210/what-could-time-crystals-be-useful-for). I can imagine that the periodic time change can help somehow increase decoherence times which are low in current qRAMs. **However, I was not able to find any details on how time crystals can actually help in qRAM design. Could anybody shed more light on this?**

*Additional question to Google's claim - did they really prepare the time crystal or rather did they simulate a quantum system behaving like the time crystal?*

**[Cross-posted on Quantum computing SE](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/20846/how-can-time-crystals-be-useful-in-qram-design)**

Comment: FWIW, I am not aware of any scientific proposal (that is, appearing in a journal article, even in a vague or offhand way) for this application of time crystals, or indeed almost any application that one sees thrown about in these popular articles. Caveat lector.

Comment: For example, the Google paper that you link says nothing about any applications, or goals beyond studying non-equilibrium phases of matter (a wonderful pursuit in itself, to be sure).